# Powershell GUI / Forms - Not creating Active Directory account

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I'm not very good at titling things so firstly, apologies if the title is a little random.

I am building a Powershell GUI script for easy Active Directory user creation, however when I submit it does not create the account.

I have tried redefining the variables and rewriting the actual user creation script.

I haven't included all locations as it would make the code even longer, however below is all of the relevant code.

Hope you genius' can help!

```
Function Display-UserCreation {
    $PasswordValue = "Annodata" + [system.web.security.membership]::GeneratePassword(9, 2)
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $PasswordValue -AsPlainText -Force

    $DisplayName = $UCFirstNameParam + " " + $UCsurNameParam
    $Mail = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam + "@" + "annodata.co.uk"
    $MailAlias = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam + "@" + $DNSRoot2

    $SInitial = $UCsurNameParam[0]
    $Initial = $UCFirstNameParam[0]
    $SAMAccountName = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam
    $SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
    $UserPrincipalName = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam

    $defaultname = $SAMAccountName
    $email = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam
    $i = 1

    While ((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SAMAccountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null) {
        $SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i 
        $Mail = $email + [string]$i + "@" + "annodata.co.uk"
        $i++
    }

    if ( $UCLocationParam -EQ 'Bracknell' ) {
        $NewUserParams = @{
            path                  = "OU=Bracknell,OU=Sites,DC=annodata,DC=co,DC=uk"
            SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
            Name                  = $SAMAccountName
            DisplayName           = $DisplayName
            GivenName             = $UCFirstNameParam
            Surname               = $UCsurNameParam
            EmailAddress          = $Mail
            UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@annodata.co.uk"
            Description           = $UCRoleParam
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
            PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
            AccountPassword       = $password
            Enabled               = $true
        }
        New-ADUser @NewUserParams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $SAMAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force)
    }
}

Function UCSubmit {
    if ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please Confirm That The Details Are Correct. If they are, click ok", "Confirmation", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OkCancel) -eq "Ok") {

        $UCFirstNameParamLong = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text = $UCFirstName.Text
        $UCFirstNameParamLong.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 100)
        $UCFirstNameParamLong.AutoSize = $true
        $UCFirstNameParamLong.Font = 'Georgia,10'

        $UCSurnameParamLong = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $UCSurnameParamLong.Text = $UCSurname.Text
        $UCSurnameParamLong.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 150)
        $UCSurnameParamLong.AutoSize = $true
        $UCSurnameParamLong.Font = 'Georgia,10'

        $UCRoleParamLong = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $UCRoleParamLong.Text = $UCRole.Text
        $UCRoleParamLong.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 200)
        $UCRoleParamLong.AutoSize = $true
        $UCRoleParamLong.Font = 'Georgia,10'

        $UCLocationParamLong = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $UCLocationParamLong.Text = $UCSiteSelection.Text
        $UCLocationParamLong.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180, 250)
        $UCLocationParamLong.AutoSize = $true
        $UCLocationParamLong.Font = 'Georgia,10'

        $UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
        $UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
        $UCRoleParam = $UCRoleParamLong.Text
        $UCLocationParam = $UCLocationParamLong.Text

        Display-UserCreation
    }
}
```

Comment: `Display-UserCreation` is missing its `}` (needs to be added on line above `Function UCSubmit`)

Comment: Remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` from line with `New-ADUser` and you'll get at least the error why the user is not created. And it would be nice if you'll add an exception handling.

Comment: @JamesC.

That was user error on adding the code to this, in the actual code it's there, i just had to snip bits out to paste it here and accidentally snipped out the closing }

Comment: @montonero already tried that, it doesn't throw any error at all.

which is baffling to me

Comment: Do you expect any output beside the creation of the AD-User? What output do you get in either case?

Comment: @T-Me I expect it to create the AD account, i haven't set up an actual output of data yet, however before I set up the creation side of things, I made it print the parameters so that I could see that they were being grabbed.

Comment: It seems you check the input in `UCSubmit` before starting `Display-UserCreation`. Is that right? Try to display the `$NewUserParams` right before `New-ADUser @NewUserParams` and keep the `-ErrorAction` removed till the problem is resolved.

Comment: @T-Me With the error action removed it doesn't throw any error, if anything it doesn't show anything.

The new user params are right before the New-ADUser

I'm not sure what you mean by the "Check the input in UCSubmit".

To give some context, the main page of the GUI are 3 text boxes, a dropdown menu and a submit button. UCSubmit is the submit button on that gui;

The submit button then collects the data, converts them into variables then the User creation section grabs those variables.

If that makes sense in any way

Comment: Make a `try..except` block around `New-ADUser` and catch all errors (add `-ErrorAction stop`). Also try to add `-PassThru` to `New-ADUser` and see if it will return a created user object or not.

Comment: @montonero I am not familiar with Try..except. Could you explain :)

Comment: Apologies, I meant `try..catch` of course.

Comment: @montonero I'm still not familiar with that. 

Could we open up a chat and assist there? just so this doesn't get clogged

Comment: Sure. But I've never used StackOverflow chats so please be my host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187425/discussion-between-james-timms-and-montonero).

Comment: See above @montonero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference to everybody.

It looks like it wasn't navigating at first to the creation function.

Once that was resolved, it wasn't running the IF. 
I had to change the parameter of the IF.

After that, the password complexity wasn't enough as for some reason the password wasn't generating.

I have now changed this and it is all resolved.